# Paypal Adaptive payments ipn error

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm encountering an error with my PHP paypal adaptive payments IPN URL, I have narrowed it down to this:

Paypal returns

```
Array
(
[Errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Receiver] => 
                [Category] => Application
                [Domain] => PLATFORM
                [ErrorID] => 580001
                [ExceptionID] => 
                [Message] => Invalid request: {0}
                [Parameter] => 
                [Severity] => Error
                [Subdomain] => Application
            )

    )

[Ack] => Failure
[Build] => 15089777
[CorrelationID] => 0a7dc3c7614d8
[Timestamp] => 2015-02-09T04:50:15.458-08:00
[PayKey] => 
[PaymentExecStatus] => 
[RedirectURL] => 
[XMLRequest] => ReturnAllen_USPAYhttp://myurl.com/cancel.phpAPP-80W284485P519543T76561198031633135141.101.98.145USDSECONDARYONLYhttp://myurl.com/?uid=123&pid=2Purchase Plugin1kuro@bob.comtrue0.75john@c16.comfalsetrue22123124156123http://myurl.com/return.php
[XMLResponse] => 2015-02-09T04:50:15.458-08:00Failure0a7dc3c7614d815089777580001PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationInvalid request: {0}
)
```

Ive narrowed it down to my IPN URL and its GET data.

```
http://myurl.com/?uid=123&pid=2
```

Paypal returns created if i do a single variable, so it seems that adding the & sign breaks it. I replaced the & with a + and it created the request, i also manually fed the ipn_url setting the data so its nothing to do with missing variables php side. SO im puzzled what to do about it.

Comment: Sounds like you might have simply neglected to URL-encode that value properly at some point where it gets put into an URL context …

Comment: Well there's not much else i can do to to `$ipn_url = "http://bob.com/?uid=".urlencode("123")."&pid=".urlencode("2");`

Comment: Is that URL put into another URL (PayPal address) as a parameter value? If so, you have to URL-Encode the _whole_ value, not the individual parts.